# What is the best way to update a record getting the key from another table?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am learning how realtime databases work, so be patient.
To better explain my doubt, I take an image showing the relevant part of the realtime database

https://prnt.sc/p0wmvs

All I want is the best way to update the field "name" of a record "grps".
The starting point is the "usrs" table where I can reference

```
mFD.getReference("usrs/"+user.getUid()+"/asAdm/grps/"+grpId)
```

My function to update "name" of group name

```
public void editGroupFromUser(long grpID, Group group, final DataStatus dataStatus) {

    DatabaseReference mFRUser = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference(
            "usrs/"+user.getUid()+"/asAdm/gprs/"+grpID
    );

    mFRUser.child("grp").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String groupKey = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();

            DatabaseReference mFRGroup = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("grps");

            mFRGroup.child( groupKey ).setValue(group).addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
                dataStatus.DataIsUpdated();
            });

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });

}
```

The need to receive the group key to then send the group update. This does not seem efficient at all.
Also, the need to send the user Uid key when the user is identified in firebase does not seem safe at all.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with this code?

Comment: The need to receive the group key to then send the group update. This does not seem efficient at all.
Also, the need to send the user Uid key when the user is identified in firebase does not seem safe at all.